# Matrix Multiplication multiprocess in C

Tags: c, multiprocessing, matrix-multiplication

I want to do matrix multiplication using multiple processes via fork and using shared memory with each of the process computing one row for small sized matrix but with higher sized matrices it is not possible to create a process for each row . So It should compute a block of rows determined by the size. For example upto 10 rows it should calculate one row per process and after that say for 20 rows one process should calculate  4 rows each. I am unable to program it as I can take row number as number of processes. Suppose I take number of processes constant say 8 then each block would have N/8 rows.But then size of matrix should be multiple of 8, and number of processes should be variable.Suppose it has 6 CPUs , Can I take number of processes to be constant i e 6 .What can be the right approach ? How should I write it ?

Comment: I feel like a little googling here would go a long way as this has been done many, many times before.

Comment: I could not find any sample matrix multiplication program in C which would depict matrix multiplication using processes and shared memory and way to optimize it

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code which demonstrates matrix mult. in pthreads. I found it almost instantly in a search engine.  It shows a method for doing what you describe.
http://www.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs422/spring13/examples/matmult-dyn.c

You'll probably need to do some fine tuning of it to determine what is the best approach.

You probably should also read this article:
http://aristeia.com/TalkNotes/PDXCodeCamp2010.pdf

Comment: I'm using processes instead of threads in it and I could not find it on search engine ...

Comment: Yes of course.  I didn't pick up on that initially.  I suspect that threading is a more tractable way to approach this problem, perhaps why I missed it the first time around.  Either way there's no reason to create any more processes (or threads) than you have cores available to run them on.  The rest is just overhead.

Comment: So should I limit number of processes to 6 ? and make each process do N/6 rows ?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly without benchmarking... That said, I think I would start out by taking the number of rows divided by the number of CPUs, and dishing that many rows out to each.  If it doesn't come out evenly, you'll need to handle the remainder at the end, obviously.  You're doing the work in parallel across all the cores, but not constantly coming back to ask for more.

Comment: Alright , thanks , I will try doing the same , though I am not sure how would I handle remainder

Comment: Well, suppose for example you have 4 left over at the end, and 6 processes that could process them.  Just put one of the 4 on each of the first 4, and signal that others that you don't need them anymore.   This is a bit like handwaving, because you haven't shown any specifics on exactly how you're going to communicate with the processes.